# Redirect to another HTML page after successfull login attempt | with JS

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have created a login form. I want a JS code that:

1. If the information on the login page i.e Username and Login is correct, It will proceed to another HTML page.
   *Simply*, I want the page to redirect to another page after successfull login attempt. | With JS
2. I dont want any PHP or MySql code.

   I have tried this code but this doesnt works. On wrong information, it says Invalid information. But on correct info, it refreshes the page and there a ? is visible at te end of the url:

Html:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email"  id="email" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" >
        </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg shadow" onClick="auth()">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
        function auth() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    
        if (email === "admin@gmail.com" && password === "user") {
            location = location['href'];
            // alert("You Are a ADMIN");
    
        } else {
            alert("Invalid information");
            return;
        }
    
    }
```

I have also used:

```
window.location.replace("upload.html");
```

instead of:

```
location = location['href'];
```

But still does not works.

Comment: Now to be honest here, you really shouldn't be putting authentication like this in your web pages. You're laying out the user and password right there in the code along with the redirect which you're trying to protect. You really should have some server side validation here, and some kind of protection on the target page to stop someone from just navigating there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here. One you're doing a `GET` with your form rather than doing a `POST`. You should change that. Second, on your JavaScript call for `auth` you should pass the `event` parameter so that the default action of the form will be stopped. Third, you should be using a relative path for your `URL` within your redirect. Last, You should do a `window.redirect()` to simulate an HTTP redirect when the function executes.

Here is the code with the updates:

```
<form id="form" action="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
       <input type="email"  
              id="email" 
              class="form-control"  
              aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
        <small id="emailHelp" 
                class="form-text text-muted">
             We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
       <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" 
             class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg shadow" 
             onClick="auth(event)">Submit</button>
 </form>
 <script>
    function auth(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
          var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

          if (email === "admin@gmail.com" && password === "user") {
               window.location.replace("/upload.html");
          } else {
              alert("Invalid information");
              return;
          }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks bro a lot. You really can't imagine how happy I am with that. It worked instantly!

Comment: If you could accept this answer, that would be great.